# How to emit an event derived from the result of a modal dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

What I'm trying to do: my component has three buttons, two "default" options and a modal dialog option for further options. The default options cause my component to emit an event derived from the corresponding option and component's other data. Clicking on the "modal dialog" option opens a modal dialog with more options, and the event should be emitted immediately when the dialog closes.

```ts
@Component{
selector:'my-component'
//...
}
export class MyComponent{
  //...
  @Output() eventEmitter:EventEmitter<MyEvent>=new EventEmitter();
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
  //...
  onSelection(value:string){
    console.log('selection',value);
    this.eventEmitter.emit(new MyEvent(value,this.otherData));
  }

  showExtendedModal(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyModalComponent,{
      data:{
       stuff:this.stuff
      },
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(value=>this.onSelection(value))
  }
}
```

The parent component's template includes `<my-component (eventEmitter)="doAThing($event)></my-component>"` inside an `*ngFor` that iterates over a derived table. The first line of `doAThing` is a call to `console.log`.

I can see the `console.log` happen, but the parent component that binds to the event doesn't log receiving the event.

What I have tried:

- Create an `EventEmitter` in `MyModalComponent`, emit an event before closing and subscribe to that event. I get the same result.
- Store `const emit=this.eventEmitter.bind(this.eventEmitter)` in the onClick, and pass an arrow function calling that to `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe`. Once again, the same result.
- Pass the result of `this.onSelection.bind(this)` in the `data` parameter. The event doesn't reach the parent component there either.
- Make a "pendingSelection:string|null" field, set it in the `subscribe` callback, check that field in `ngOnChanges` and emit according to that. The field isn't set when `ngOnChanges` gets invoked.

I tried adding `console.log(eventEmitter)` to `onSelection`. When it works, the output looks like this:

```json
{
  "closed": false,
  "currentObservers": null,
  "observers": [],
  "isStopped": false,
  "hasError": false,
  "thrownError": null,
  "__isAsync": false
}
```

However, when the event is emitted from the callback, it looks like this:

```json
{
  "closed": false,
  "currentObservers": [],
  "observers": [],
  "isStopped": false,
  "hasError": false,
  "thrownError": null,
  "__isAsync": false
}
```

The only difference I can see is that `currentObservers` is null in one and empty in another.

I have tried to recreate this issue with a smaller project. This did not succeed.

How do I emit an event after a modal dialog closes, so that the parent component receives it?

Comment: Can you provide relevant code from parent component? If console logs value in `onSelection` method, then obviously value is nexted to `eventEmitter` as expected. As a side note, EventEmitter in Angular is Subject from rxjs observables. It's convenient to use Subject and not introduce another object type.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis The relevant code is a typical Angular binding of an event to a function, and the function starts with a `console.log`. I have added this to my question.

Comment: My attempt to recreate this in a small project has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution for my particular case. I'm adding it as an answer on the off chance that someone runs into the same issue.

The underlying is that I was using many getters that return a snapshot, which means that change detection triggers a lot. I had an `*ngFor="let foo of complicatedGetter"` up the component tree  that I believe caused some sort of race condition related to change detection.

My solution was to add `typescript-memoize` to the project and annotate `complicatedGetter` with `@Memoize()`. However, at time of writing, the npm package is three months old. Any other memoization approach should also work.